# Can somebody explain "alienating customers" and "on either side" in this context for me?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"UK banks have been fearful of alienating customers on either side, while eurozone-headquartered institutions can more easily relocate business from London back to their home countries in the event of a vote to leave."

source: http://www.cnbc.com/2016/03/29/bank-of-america-bans-staff-from-saying-brexit.html

Answer (score 1):

"Alienating customers" means turning customers away or making them feel unwelcome as customers of the bank.

"on either side" is referring to those in favour of, and against, the UK remaining in the EU.

Putting them together, the bank is trying to avoid discouraging anyone as a customer, whether they want the UK to stay in the EU or leave.